# ImageProcessing in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am New to Windows phone 8.1 ,  Currently I am making a small APP related to image processing . But I am confused .

like in simple C# we do setpixel() and getpixel() . 
But I dont understand , how can I Perform the same in this platform .

I will be very thankful for the help .

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: Hi, a search for `windows phone getpixel setpixel` seems to yield very useful results?

Comment: no a basic windows phone image processing tutorial link would be very great full

Comment: What do you want to do as image processing?

Comment: WriteableBitmapEx allows you to access pixels. http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am making a collage APP , So , in this I need a small Image Processing in certain areas of images. @MuhammadSaifullah

Answer (score 1):

Nokia Image SDK is powerfull image processing tool for windows phone. Following are some resources where you can download and how to use samples.

[Nokia Imaging SDK Home](http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging)

[Sample Projects](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk/sample-projects.html)

[API Reference](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Imaging_API_Ref/)

Hope this helps